# What does the `Let Windows Desktop Search search for PDF documents` option in Sumatra PDF do?

Tags: windows, pdf, search, sumatra-pdf

When installing Sumatra PDF, I see the `Let Windows Desktop Search search for PDF documents` option.

[image]

What does the `Let Windows Desktop Search search for PDF documents` option in Sumatra PDF do? Does that mean that Windows Desktop Search would use Sumatra PDF to be able to index/search content from all PDFs on the user's computer?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the `Let Windows Desktop Search search for PDF documents` option during the Sumatra PDF installation will install an [IFilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) that will allow Microsoft's search engine to index PDF files, using Sumatra PDF to access the content of a PDF file.

FYI: [Is the Sumatra IFilter better than Windows 10 default?](https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/is-the-sumatra-ifilter-better-than-windows-10-default/2883)